# Math isn't adding up from what is being output

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, int

I am currently attempting to make a very basic random number game. Everything seems to be working the way it should minus the fact that the math isn't adding up.
You get 3 options 1) Attack, 2) Heal, 3) Exit Game. Each one functions as intended and display what should be expected, minus the fact that the math does not add up.

`---------------------
Beau hit the monster for 10 damage!
The Monster hit Beau for 18 damge!
You now have 81 health points!
The monster now has 80 health points!
---------------------`

I'm honestly not sure what I am missing and kind of feel like an idiot.

here is the source.

```
from random import randint

game_running = True


def calculate_monster_attack(attack_min, attack_max):
    return randint(attack_min,attack_max)


def calculate_player_attack(attack_min, attack_max):
    return randint(attack_min, attack_max)


def calculate_player_healing(healing_min, healing_max):
    return randint(healing_min, healing_max)


while  game_running == True:
    new_round = True
    player = {'attack_min': 10, 'attack_max': 20, 'healing_min': 10, 'healing_max': 18, 'health': 100}
    monster = {'name': 'Monster', 'attack_min': 10, 'attack_max': 20, 'health': 100}
print('---' * 7)
print('Enter Player name!')
player['name'] = input()

while new_round == True:

    player_won = False
    monster_won = False

    print('---' *7)
    print('Please select an action')
    print('---' *7)
    print('1) Attack')
    print('---' *7)
    print('2) Heal')
    print('---' *7)
    print('3) Exit Game')

    player_choice = input()
    print('---' *7)

    if player_choice == '1':

        monster['health'] = monster['health'] - calculate_player_attack(player['attack_min'], player['attack_max'])
        print(player['name'] + ' hit the monster for {} damage!'.format(calculate_player_attack(player['attack_min'], player['attack_max'])))

        if monster['health'] <= 0:
            player_won = True

        else:
            player['health'] = player['health'] - calculate_monster_attack(monster['attack_min'], monster['attack_max'])
            print('The ' + (monster['name'] + ' hit ' + player['name'] + ' for {} damage!'.format(calculate_monster_attack(monster['attack_min'], monster['attack_max']))))

            if player['health'] <=0:
                monster_won = True

    elif player_choice == '2':

        player['health'] = player['health'] + calculate_player_healing()
        print('You healed yourself and now have {} health points!'.format(player['health']))

        print('The ' + (monster['name'] + ' hit ' + player['name'] + ' for {} damge!'.format(calculate_monster_attack(monster['attack_min'], monster['attack_max']))))
        player['health'] = player['health'] - calculate_monster_attack(monster['attack_min'], monster['attack_max'])

        if player['health'] <=0:
            monster_won = True

    elif player_choice == '3':
        new_round = False
        game_running = False
    else:
        print('Invalid Input')

    if player_won == False and monster_won == False:
        print('You now have {} health points!'.format(player['health']))
        print('The monster now has {} health points!'.format(monster['health']))

    elif monster_won:
        print('Oh no! Better luck next time ' + player['name'] + ', the monster won this round!')
        new_round = False

    elif player_won:
        print('Congratulations ' + player['name'] + ' you beat the monster!')
        new_round = False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your game calculates damage twice for each attack, once before print, once in print. Try to save the value of first attack damage calculation and use that value in print, instead of calculate another random value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm just getting pack into programming in general. I'm not a 100% sure how to save the value of the first attack damage calculation and then use that store value to print it out. I've messed around with trying to make another function and then call that function while trying to store the previous function. I'm sure that is 100% wrong so please feel free to let me know. I've googled around a bit as well and haven't found much in the way of helping me solve my issue.

Comment: Something like ”damage = calculate_player_attack(player['attack_min'], player['attack_max']);    monster['health'] = monster['health'] - damage; ”  should work.